# Setting fallback image source for svg:image in react

Tags: reactjs, image, svg, fallback

We have the following `svg:image` on our site, however the `href` that is linked to `https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105672-979339.png` is unavailable.

```
<image x="-4.75" y="0" width="65" height="65" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/cbb-image-files/PlayerHeadshots/105672-979339.png" mask="url(#ellipse-mask)" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></image>
```

The image was reacted in react like so

```
    const playerImage =
        (<image
            x={xVal}
            y={yVal}
            width={logoRadius}
            height={logoRadius}
            href={playerUrl} // bad URL in question
            mask='url(#ellipse-mask)'
        />);
```

How is it possible to add a fallback URL in case the url at `href` is not working? We've tried adding a `src` to the code with a valid URL but this is not fixing the issue when the image renders. How can this be handled? We have to use svg:image as this image is rendering inside of an svg (html  not an option)

Comment: add an onerror handler and then replace the href using javascript.

Comment: svg:image has an onError option?

Comment: https://bug500261.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=385088